# random fetch display data to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

basically i wish to random the item display in dropdownlist ,any function can work with it?

**output**

a

b

c

**expected output (can be any but not only abc)**

b

a

c

OR

c

a

b

OR

any

---

asp:Label ID="Label3" Text=' <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question")%> ' Runat="server"

---

Select * from (SELECT [r1] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question)

UNION SELECT [r2] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question) UNION

SELECT [r3] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question AND

[r3]!=null))t Order by Newid()"

Comment: Any? order by Desc would do it?

Comment: erm, order by desc is not what i want, what i want is to random the output><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `Newid()` to get the random order

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [r1] AS [Option]
        FROM   [ExerciseTable]
        WHERE  ( [Question] = @Question )
        UNION
        SELECT [r2] AS [Option]
        FROM   [ExerciseTable]
        WHERE  ( [Question] = @Question )
        UNION
        SELECT [r3] AS [Option]
        FROM   [ExerciseTable]
        WHERE  ( [Question] = @Question
                 AND [r3] != NULL )) t
ORDER  BY Newid()
```

**UPDATE**

FOR TEST :

CODE:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'a' AS col
        UNION
        SELECT 'b' AS col
        UNION
        SELECT 'c' AS col) t
ORDER  BY Newid()
```

First Time

[image]

Second Time

[image]

Comment: you should get the random order .